# VS не видит Newton Json.Net

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio-2019, json.net, newtonsoft.json

Библиотеку установил с помощью менеджера пакетов нугет, при этом в коде для юнити VS не видит эту библиотеку. Что нужно сделать, чтобы он начал видеть эту библиотеку?

Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json; // Вот эту библиотеку не видит и выдает ошибку

namespace DB
{

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Stats : MonoBehaviour
    {

        

        public PlayerData playerData;
        Player player = new("Mendzek", 30, 5);
        public ForPlayerData forPlayerData;
        [HideInInspector]
        public string path = "D:\\Unity\\Unity projects\\Darkest Bone\\Darkest Bone\\Assets";
        [HideInInspector]
        public string jsonPlayerStats = "Player stats.json";
        private void Start()
        {
            
            forPlayerData.data = new List<Player>();
            forPlayerData.data.Add(player);
            savePlayerStats();
            loadPlayerStats();
            Debug.Log("Name: " + playerData.name + " HP: " + playerData.HP + " damage: " + playerData.damage);
            
        }
        void savePlayerStats()
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(player);
            File.WriteAllText(path, json);
        }
        void loadPlayerStats()
        {
            player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(path + jsonPlayerStats);
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка:
`Assets\Skripts\Stats.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: В Unity нет NuGet, то, что вы добавляете, это C# проект, C# код, но сам Unity, он работает при помощи ассетов, у него есть свой [магазин ассетов](https://assetstore.unity.com), через который все ставится. Ну а если вы хотите использовать NuGet, то либо вручную переносите пакеты, либо делайте что-то [такое](https://medium.com/@alexandredemersroberge/use-nuget-packages-with-unity-25b8525f628), либо пытайтесь [внедрить NuGet](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, кто запретит добавить `Visual Studio` что-то в проект из `NuGet`? Вполне себе скачает и поместит в папку `Packages`. Другое дело что, как `Visual Studio` может добавить, `Unity` может убрать то что ему не понравится, как тот-же `System.Text.Json`, которого в проекте быть не должно.

Comment: @Yaroslav Об этом я и написал выше. Что касается "не должно быть", тут яб поспорил, ибо стандартные компоненты Unity весьма скудны в плане JSON, а тот-же JSON.NET довольно сильная штука, которая ставиться спокойно в Unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unity3D Json

Не видит `Newtonsoft.Json`, потому, что этой библиотеки нет. Открой `Ссылки` в `Assembly-CSharp` в твоем проекте и сам посмотри.

Более того под `IL2CPP`, она не работает, как и `System.Text.Json`, который так-же отсутствует в сборе `Unity` в виду бесполезнлсти.

Для работы с объектами в `Unity` есть [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html).

```
public class JsonUtilityTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string Key = "Test";

    private struct TestPiggy
    {
        public int value;
    }

    [ContextMenu("Save")]
    public void Save ()
    {
        TestPiggy myPiggy = new TestPiggy() { value = 1 };
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(myPiggy);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(Key, json);
        Debug.Log(json);
    }

    [ContextMenu("Load")]
    public void Load ()
    {
        string json = PlayerPrefs.GetString(Key);
        TestPiggy myPiggy = JsonUtility.FromJson<TestPiggy>(json);
        Debug.Log(myPiggy.value);
    }
}
```

Для работы с кастумными `JsonObject`, есть решения в [Asset Store](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-object-710).

Comment: Всё изменится с приходом CoreCLR в Unity :)

Comment: @aepot, да поскорее бы уже, но в этом году появиться только для "настольных платформ" и чувствую что вся тема ОЧЕНЬ долго будет в статусе `beta` D=

Comment: @aepot, да и речь идет больше про производительность. Читал [we have the dream to combine CoreCLR JIT/AOT, IL2CPP and Burst technologies](https://forum.unity.com/threads/expected-performance-of-new-coreclr-vs-mono-vs-il2cpp.1403353/), и фиг его знает, сможем ли мы наконец написать заветный `using System.Text.Json;` или все так-же придется `using Defective.JSON;`.